# How to get country name from IP address in php

Tags: php, ip-address, country

I want to find country, city, latitude and longitude from IP address using php. I am using this url and it is returning data in xml format.

http://www.ipgp.net/api/xml/122.163.6.58

The data is coming like this:

```xml
<IpLookup>
    <Ip>122.163.6.58</Ip>
    <Code>IN</Code>
    <Country>India</Country>
    <Flag>http://www.ipgp.net/flags/in.png</Flag>
    <City>Calcutta</City>
    <Region>West Bengal</Region>
    <Isp></Isp>
    <Lat>22.5697</Lat>
    <Lng>88.3697</Lng>
</IpLookup>
```

Can anybody suggest how to parse and get the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [XML parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) included in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this personally:
http://ipinfodb.com/

The examples are very clear and concise and the API is very fast.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The use of API in PHP has already described in their website. Why you use but don't read?

http://www.ipgp.net/developer-tools/

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use `xpath` this is more easier schema for accessing the attributes.
for example for your current data i have the following:

```
$file = 'file.xml';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file, NULL, TRUE);
$ipz = $xml->xpath("/IpLookup/Ip");
$country = $xml->xpath("/IpLookup/Country/");
foreach($ipz as $ip)
{
    foreach($country as $country)
    {
      echo $ip.'<br/>';
      echo $country.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

this code will return you the `ip` and the `country` for your current `xml`. you can edit it in your own way.