# Php if selection by origin visitor (ip adress)

Tags: php, country

i have this code in my shopping cart (magento 1.6.2)

```
<?php if ($this->getQuote()->getSubtotal() < 41.28): ?>
<?php $subtotalamt = $this->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); ?>
<?php $freeshipamt = 41.28; ?>
<?php $sumtotal = ($freeshipamt - $subtotalamt )* 1.21; ?>
<?php Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($sumtotal); ?>
<p>Gratis verzending vanaf € 49,95 <br/>(binnen Nederland)</p><p>
<strong>Nog <span>€ <?php print number_format($sumtotal, 2, ',', ' '); ?></span> 
tot gratis verzending!</strong></p>
<?php else: ?><p><strong>Uw bestelling wordt GRATIS verzonden!</strong> <br/>(binnen Nederland)</p>
<?php endif ?>
<?php /* You are just <span>$<?php print ($sumtotal); ?></span> away from earning free shipping!</p> */ ?>
```

This code calculates the needed amount for the customer to receive free shipping within the Netherlands.

Is there a way to add some code so when a vistor from a other country visits our webshop the amount is changed for free shipping. Like germany or belgium. They receive free shipping from 149,95.

I guess there should be a `php if` whick can determine the origin of the vistors ip-adress.
Can anyone help me to set this up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get country name from IP address in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191489/how-to-get-country-name-from-ip-address-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The are some IP to Country databases and APIs. APIs might work just fine but you will end up paying some money for them...

Take your time to check this PHP Class + DB:

https://github.com/magorski/php-ip-2-country

PS: Maybe the DBs are not so bad, right now I'm using on a real system some PHP class with a simple DB that does the job and is much smaller than that one I pointed you at. (Maybe less precise or something).